# How to exempt element to be validated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the validation plugin for jquery:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation.

I want to know how would I exempt a field to be validated? Currently all fields inside the form are automatically checked.

---

I am not sure if this will help since the element that I want to exempt is not included (obviously :) )

```
  $("#contactForm").validate({
      rules: {
                        first_name:{required: true,charsonly:true,minlength: 1 },
                        last_name:{required:true,charsonly:true,minlength: 1 },
                        birthday:{required:true,min:1,max:31 },
                        birthmonth:"required",
                        birthyear:"required",
                        username: {required: true,minlength:1,maxlength:32,username:true,notChinese:true,noSpecial:true},
                        password1:{required:true,minlength: 5,maxlength: 10, alphaNum: true },
                        password2:{required:true,minlength: 5,maxlength: 10, alphaNum: true, equalTo: "#password1"},
                        currency:"required",
                        address:{required: true,noSpecial:true,minlength:2},
                        city:{required: true,noSpecial:true,minlength:2},
                        state:{noSpecial:true},
                        countrycode:"required",
                        zip:{required:true,zipTest:true},
                        email:{required:true,email:  true},
                        confirmemail:{required: true,equalTo:  "#email",email:true},
                        phone:{required: true,minlength:6,maxlength:20,phoneUS:true},
                        cellphone:{required: true,minlength:6,maxlength:20,phoneUS:true},
                        custom06:{acceptIM:true}

      } });
```

---

Found it.
I used the ignore validation method.

---

Here's the code

```
$("#myform").validate({
   ignore: ".ignore"
})
```

Comment: just to clarify. What I want to do is remove this

<label for="custom06" generated="true" class="error checked">&nbsp;</label>

the plugin automatically appends this code even if there is no validation for that element.

Comment: It seems the problem stems from using a global rules function instead of setting the class per element. still I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some sort of server side technology? The validation library needs to have rules set, and if you are doing this in strictly javaScript (jQuery) it is manual.

**UPDATE:** You can remove rules with the following: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22remove.22rules

Place the following at the end of the body.

```
$("selector").rules("remove");
```

Comment: nope. and the field that I want to be exempted is not in the rules [meaning I didn't add any because I didn't want it validated].

Answer (score 0):

It depends on class attribute. See examples:

This field is required and email format: it cannot be empty

```
input class="required email"
```

This field is NOT required and email format: it can be empty

```
input class="email"
```

This field is NOT required and doesnt have format: it can be empty

```
input class=""
```

Comment: This does not work as I've added an image to the label that the plugin attaches to each element (x or check).

Answer (score 0):

You could set your own messages:

```
$("#contactForm").validate({
      rules: {
         input1: required,
         input2: required,
         no-validation: required,
         input4: required,
      },
      messages: {
         no-validation: ''
      }
});
```

Just put an empty string for the field you don´t want to show any message for..